# GPIO-LED Inter Process Communication via Shared Memory in BeagleBoard Black

Tags: gpio, beagleboneblack

Can some one please give us code for controlling gpio and on board led from a C program and which also has shared memory communication

Comment: *"give us code"* --> www.kernel.org

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [link](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Gpio-int-test.c) for gpio-control code.

What you mean by "which also has shared memory communication" and Why do you need it is unclear from your question?